# Intuit Partner Platform to ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

How to connect a Quick book with asp.net using Intuit Partner Platform.
What are the things i should configure in the web config.
Please provide a sample coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB the sample web.config

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/blob/master/QuickbooksAPI/DotNet/WebForms%20application/QuickBooksApiDotNetWebFormsSampleApp/Web.config

You can refer the QB guide from the link below

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/@api/deki/files/1381/gettingstartedwithquickbooks.pdf

for consumer key and consumer secret
[ Ref - page 9 ]

Hope it will be useful

Thanks